# How to stub a method which does not have a return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mocha.js

I am using Mocha, and I want to stub a method which does not have a return value.
It looks something like this

```
def some_method
 increment_counter+=1
 database_model.update_attributes(:column => "something")
end
```

how do I test teh functionality of this method, and see if the database model is updated?

Answer (score 0):

```
def some_method
  increment_counter+=1
  database_model.update_attributes(:column => "something")
  updated_database_model = Model.find(database_model.id)
  updated_database_model.column.should == "something"
end
```